# javafx.base cannot be resolved to a module in vscode

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, configuration

I am on a java project where I need to use javafx but vscode does not recognize it.
[image: screen of the error]
I add In the Java Projects all the .jar from the javafx librarie like this:
[image: References Libraries]
I have try a lot of thing without any luck. Do you have an idea of how to fix that?

I have tried to modif the settings.json inside the .vscode like this:

```
json
{
    "java.classPath": [
        "/path/to/library1.jar",
        "/path/to/library2.jar"
    ],
    "java.project.referencedLibraries": [
        "lib/**/*.jar",
        "/usr/lib/javafx-sdk-15.0.1/lib/javafx.base.jar",
        "/usr/lib/javafx-sdk-15.0.1/lib/javafx.controls.jar",
        "/usr/lib/javafx-sdk-15.0.1/lib/javafx.fxml.jar",
        "/usr/lib/javafx-sdk-15.0.1/lib/javafx.graphics.jar",
        "/usr/lib/javafx-sdk-15.0.1/lib/javafx.media.jar",
        "/usr/lib/javafx-sdk-15.0.1/lib/javafx.swing.jar",
        "/usr/lib/javafx-sdk-15.0.1/lib/javafx.web.jar",
        "/usr/lib/javafx-sdk-15.0.1/lib/javafx-swt.jar",
        "/home/ronan/Documents/Projets/Bin/JizLib.jar",
        "/home/ronan/Documents/Projets/Bin/JizoM.jar",
        "/home/ronan/Documents/Projets/Bin/JizoMSrv.jar",
        "/home/ronan/Documents/Projets/Bin/Task.jar",
        "/home/ronan/Documents/Projets/ppg/src/org/phypo/PPg/PPgLib.jar"
    ]
}
```

But this does not change anything.

Comment: May I know what's going on with the problem? If it has been solved, can you change the status of the answer to help more people with similar problems.

Comment: The solution was to go on InteliJ, and I think the problem was I was building with a makefile the javaprojet and the lsp of vscode cant resolve this way.

Comment: If you find the solution, Please consider answering it and accepting it as an answer to change its status to Answered. It will also help others to solve a similar issue. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following setting：

```json
"java.project.referencedLibraries": {
    "include": [
        "lib/**/*.jar",
        "%PATH_TO_FX%/lib/*.jar"
    ],
    "sources": {
        "%PATH_TO_FX%/lib/javafx.base.jar": "%PATH_TO_FX%/src.zip",
        "%PATH_TO_FX%/lib/javafx.controls.jar": "%PATH_TO_FX%/src.zip",
        "%PATH_TO_FX%/lib/javafx.fxml.jar": "%PATH_TO_FX%/src.zip",
        "%PATH_TO_FX%/lib/javafx.graphics.jar": "%PATH_TO_FX%/src.zip",
        "%PATH_TO_FX%/lib/javafx.media.jar": "%PATH_TO_FX%/src.zip",
        "%PATH_TO_FX%/lib/javafx.swing.jar": "%PATH_TO_FX%/src.zip",
        "%PATH_TO_FX%/lib/javafx.web.jar": "%PATH_TO_FX%/src.zip",
        "%PATH_TO_FX%/lib/javafx.swt.jar": "%PATH_TO_FX%/src.zip"
    }
}
```

[Also this document details how to use *javafx* in vscode.](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#IDE-VSCode)